# Sent etherium from Stake to my immutable wallet. Didn't get anything

Tags: immutable

I sent around 0.04 ETH to my etherium wallet, (which is connected with my email). I didn't receive anything in my wallet and now I'm wondering if I could get it.

I'm new to crypto and don't really understand how stuff work.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is the receipt: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x57f00c331df36faf338a63a86a29bba1c7075bf30b36f723bf3636af24b1141f

Comment: The transaction was for 0.004 ethers, and they are at the address [`0xf93c95c22adb0e484de0a59691c7ae5161339e6a`](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf93c95c22adb0e484de0a59691c7ae5161339e6a).